# MSSQL driver for PHP (ODBC) randomly stop sending Unicode chars

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, freetds

I'm getting data from a MSSQL database* with PHP and the ODBC/FreeTDS drivers.

I'm running PHP-FPM 7.0 and my `freetds.conf` looks like this:

```
[NAME]
host = HOST_NAME
instance = ISTANCE_NAME
tds version = 8.0
text size = 193536
```

My `/etc/odbcinst.ini` looks like this:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS Driver v0.91
Driver = /usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so
fileusage=1
dontdlclose=1
UsageCount=1
```

And my `/etc/odbc.ini`looks like this:

```
[NAME]
Description             = MSSQL Server
Driver                  = FreeTDS
Database                = DB_NAME
ServerName              = SERVE_NAME
TDS_Version             = 8.0
```

## Problem

Most of the time I'll be getting Unicode chars (đžšć etc.) back normally (on Arch as normal chars, on Ubuntu as \uXXXX chars but json_decode takes care of that). But on both systems the connection will randomly stop working correctly and start returning garbled text (i.e. "?" instead of Unicode chars).

But a restart of the php-fpm service FIXES the problem. Now I don't want to restart php-fpm every few minuets, so ... what could be the problem?

* Don't ask. You don't want to know about the "image" datatype.